# Problem with beamerarticle overlays and only

Tags: overlays, beamerarticle

I have a problem with `beamerarticle`.

First of all, I'm not that experienced with LaTeX or Beamer. I've gotten this far with samples and stuff without completely understanding, what is doing what. So that's perhaps one of the reason, I've hit the wall now.

I've made an presentation, which uses extensively the following format:

```
\begin{frame}[label=the_general]{Title of the transitioning slide}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
\only<1>{First phase before slide.}
\only<2>{Second phase before slide.}
\only<3>{Third phase before slide.}
\begin{column}{6cm}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]<1>{pic1}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]<2>{pic2}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]<3>{pic3}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{4cm}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
\only<1>{First phase side note.}
\only<2>{Second phase side note.}
\only<3>{Third phase side note.}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
\only<1>{First phase below slide.}
\only<2>{Second phase below slide.}
\only<3>{Third phase below slide.}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
```

What I get in a slide is something like this:

```
(First phase before slide.)
(pic1)   (First phase side note.)
(First) phase below slide.)
```

...and the next slide....

```
(Second phase before slide.)
(pic2)   (Second phase side note.)
(Second phase below slide.)
```

...and so on. This is perfect for me, exactly what I want, perfectly aligned pictures one after the other... Now, what I would like to have as an article is like this.

```
(First phase before slide.)
(pic1)   
(First phase side note.)
(First) phase below slide.)

(Second phase before slide.)
(pic2)   
(Second phase side note.)
(Second phase below slide.)

(Third phase before slide.)
(pic3)   
(Third phase side note.)
(Third phase below slide.)
```

But, with `beamerarticle` I'm able to get pretty pages with nice well placed headings, seemingly more perfect that I hoped for, but the sequence is:

```
(First phase before slide.)
(Second phase before slide.)
(Third phase before slide.)
(pic1)(pic2)(pic3)   
(First phase side note.)
(Second phase side note.)
(Third phase side note.)
(First) phase below slide.)
(Second phase below slide.)
(Third phase below slide.)
```

Thus completely ruining the flow of my presentation/article.

This far I've gotten with start definitions like this (before the actual frames):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\mode<article>
{
\usepackage{fullpage}
%       \setbeamertemplate{frame begin}[tikzed]
%\setbeamertemplate{frame end}[tikzed]
\usepackage{pgf}
}
```

As you can see, I've tried different things also, and with this I've gotten the closest, but not nearly close enough.

I would be very grateful, if somebody could tell me how to accomplish what I need. I've searched the net quite a bit, but haven't found the correct solutions.

Comment: Why don't you simply use 3 separate frames?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @ejoerns The foremost reason that the long presentation is already laid out like that. I have tens and tens of frames each with 10-20 "sub-slide". Another thing is that from presentation point of view the possibility to use `\only<3-9>{Text}` -type of feature helps a lot. Yes, I need to re-think that, once it is in an article format.